# What typing discipline is a programming language if there is no need for type conversion?

Tags: variables, pseudocode, typing

If I can do for example:

```
int x = 10;
string y = x;
```

And the value of y would be "10" as a string.

Which typing discipline would that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we call that [Dynamic typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Dynamic_type_checking_and_runtime_type_information)